# In Ansible, how do I use a variable in an inventory file in a template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have this inventory file

inventory/hosts_elk

```
[elk-client-0]
10.11.22.22
```

Now I have a template, and I want to do this

elk_server.yml.j2

```
elk_server = {{ elk-client-0 }}
```

But that doesn't work, that is the value for {{ elk-client-0 }} does NOT get substituted.

What is the correct syntax so when the template gets laid out on the server, the resulting file looks like

```
elk_server = 10.11.22.22
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The magic syntax is

```
elk_server: {{ groups['elk-client-0'][0] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `inventory_hostname` and/or `ansible_hostname` http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html

Comment: Maybe, but that page doesn't show how to use it in a template.

Comment: does `elk_server = {{ inventory_hostname }}` work for you?

Comment: No. Note the host I'm running the Ansible playbook is NOT elk-client-0, but another host that needs to connect to elk-client-0. So I need to replace the IP for elk-client-0 from the inventory file in resulting file.

Answer (score 0):

in terms of ansible inventory, `elk-client-0` is a host group, accessible via `groups.<name>`. 
Specifically, you want to find the 1st (or last?) host in the inventory, of specific hostgroup, so in the template you can do:

```
elk_server = {{groups.elk-client-0|random}}
```

This as of "now" will always return 1 item.
but when your host group grows, it will roll the dice.
If you need to either take always `first`, `last`, just use those filters.

Comment: Also, I am usually avoiding to add '-' characters in hostgroup names. b/c e.g. in AWS the dynamic inventory script `ec2.py` does "normalization" to host group names, converting everything into '_' (spaces, '-', etc.),

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work either, that is, I just see elk_serer = {{groups.elk-client-0|random}} in the resulting file, so the variable was not found.